# In which case does drawRect not receive the full frame of the UIView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I am writing a patch bay control, and I'm using UIViews to draw the links between the patches.

These links are subviews of a large UIView, itself a subview of a UIScrollView.

Links can become quite large, typically four times the size of the screen.
Links need to be redrawn when one of their end patch moves.

However, there are situations where only a part of the link is visible.

Instruments indicates that most of the time is spent in my QCLink drawRect method.

I have checked that the drawRect method is called with the full bounds of the QCLink each time that this QCLink need to be redrawn.

Is this a situation where I should only have to redraw a part of the UIView (the rect argument in drawRect:) ?

Here are some screen captures to help you understand the problem I'm facing.

[image: initial state]
[image: dragging a node and extending the link]
[image: he same nodes, zoomed out]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In which case does drawRect not receive the full frame of the UIView?

Your draw implementation should always be prepared to draw a portion of your view. For some tasks, the default clipping is good.

Just follow the view invalidation process -- if you invalidate a rect, then the view system traverses views and asks them to draw what lies in that rect (considering things like opacity). That rect may be (composed of) a union of rects, but that too may be clipped by the system.

So you are probably overdrawing or doing redundant drawing -- consider how that may be reduced. For starters, you might want to put all your cords in one view, and do everything you can to minimize surfaces which are not opaque. After that, you should determine where you are overdrawing. Quartz Debug can point out these redundant draws. You should be using `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` rather than `setNeedsDisplay`, especially where drawing times are critical.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a [`CATiledLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html).  Tiled layers only the draw the parts which are on screen and need to be rendered, making them great for views that may be too large for the screen or where you are going to pinch-to-zoom.  They are core to how views like `UIWebView` are rendered.

To switch your view to use a tiled layer, you just have to declare this method:

```
+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [CATiledLayer class];
}
```

You will then start seeing calls to `drawRect:` with values like `(0, 0, 256, 256)`, `(0, 256, 256, 256)`...

When moving things around, you can get an extra performance win by calling `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` instead of `setNeedsDisplay`.  This will limit drawing to the invalidated rect.

Comment: Do you mean replacing the link with a CATiledLayer subclass, or the whole view that contains links and nodes ?

Comment: The whole view. You don’t need to use a tiled layer per-link.

Comment: That depends.  Personally, I would render everything onto a single view; the performance hit of resizing a view and drawing it in entirety could be worse than just redrawing everything if its a single view.  If you do keep your lines as their own views, they they should be tiled to avoid the cost of drawing offscreen.

Comment: Assuming `QCLink` just draws a single line in `drawRect:`, you won't need to worry about modifying `drawRect:` at all.  You'll just need to add `layerClass`.

Answer (score 0):

It's always the full rectangle. What about using `CAShapeLayer`s instead?

Something like:

```
CAShapeLayer * link = [ CAShapeLayer layer ] ;
link.strokeColor = [ [ UIColor greenColor ] CGColor ] ;

CGMutablePathRef p = CGPathCreateMutable() ;
CGPathMoveToPoint( p, NULL, start ) ;
CGPathAddLineToPoint( p, NULL, end ) ;
link.path = path ;

[ parentView.layer addSublayer:link ] ;
```

Comment: Do you mean not using drawRect, but instead adding a CAShapeLayer sublayer to the QCLink backing layer ? I'd prefer to keep the link as a UIView subclass.

Comment: yes--your drawing will be faster if you avoid `-drawRect`. I.e. draw everything with paths (in shape layers) and images (in plain layers). I don't think it's necessary to put your links inside a `UIView`--it will make your code more complicated, and I guess you're not using any `UIView` features...

Comment: I would only put this in a UIView if you need to interact with the links--and then you could simply make a `UIView` subclass that adds a `CAShapeLayer` to its own layer.

Comment: I will need some user interaction eventually, and I didn't want to end up reinventing UIViews behavior starting from CALayer.

Comment: There are some tradeoffs here.  Using shape layers will have an advantage of decoupling line drawing from node drawing.  (If you move a node, you only have to render the lines that changed.)  Unfortunately, if you have `n` lines on a node, you will have `n` textures to redraw and composite, you may be better using `drawRect:`.   This also doesn't really solve the problem as far as I can tell.  For a line that is multiple screens long, the system will still have to rasterize giant textures to handle it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I assume when you call `setPath:`, the shape layer triggers `setNeedsDisplay` and will draw its path onto new `contents` rather than onto the buffer itself.  (This is where we would see some real savings.)

Comment: Performances are really good with CAShapeLayer. I tested with a few dozen of links redrawn simultaneously an it's running smoothly.